# Improving the speed of a query?

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, optimization

I am trying to improve the performance of a query.

I was thinking of using `AsNoTracking()`, but I am not sure if the location where it is put will make a difference i.e.(before `Select()` or after, before `Include()` or after, before `ToList()` or after).

I also read about `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear()`, which stops the EF from tracking changes to entities.

So will using it make my query faster?

```
var checklist = await _context.SiteCategory
                              .Include(s => s.Sites)
                              .Include(s => s.TAudits)
                              .AsNoTracking()
                              .ToListAsync();

_context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

Comment: Using `.AsNoTracking` disables the change tracker - and this will make your query and working with its returned data a bit faster, yes. `ChangeTracker.Clear()` just clears out everything the change tracker is tracking - to make sure your request really goes back to the database, and isn't served from the change tracker - but that has absolutely no effect on your query performance

Comment: *will using it make my query faster* -- measure it!

Comment: It is EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: `.Clear()` in this case has no performance impact on the code before it, `checklist` has already been loaded and because `.AsNoTracking()` is specified, the records in `checklist` are not being tracked by the tracker anyway.

Comment: Doing micro-optimization like `AsNoTracking` is going to be a small improvement comparing to actually using the minimum query you need and properly setting up your database. If you need that level of performance anyway, you are probably better off replacing EF with something more low level and high performance.

Answer (score 1):

> I also read about `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear()`, which stops the EF from tracking changes to entities.

[`DbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear?view=efcore-7.0) doesn't directly improve query performance on its own. This stops tracking all *existing tracked* entities, it doesn't stop tracking *new* entities that you load from the data store. It is faster and the preferred option to iterating through *all* tracked entities and detaching them from the context and will improve memory consumption and some logic flows if your code has discarded any references to the previous entities and you are re-using the context.

In most cases it will not improve performance of queries against a datastore, but there is an exception if you have already loaded entities that are related via FK to the records that you are about to load into the context.

This scenario can be avoided if you do not want the existing records to be linked to the results of the new query by creating a *new* context, or you can call `.Clear()` *BEFORE* you execute the new query, calling clear after the query is executed is too late, though it might improve future querues against the same context.

Another way to avoid this scenario is to load the previous queries using [`.AsNoTracking()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asnotracking?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-entityframeworkqueryableextensions-asnotracking-1(system-linq-iqueryable((-0)))) but calling `.AsNoTracking()` in your query has the same effect.

- If there are no previous queries, and so no previously tracked entities, then `.Clear()` will have no effect.
- loading the records with `.AsNoTracking()` and then calling `.Clear()` will have no effect, again because there are no tracked entities to clear.
- `.AsNoTracking()` can only be called on an `IQueryable<T>` expression, so it **MUST** be called before `.ToList()`/`.ToListAsync()`.

It is important to understand that `.AsNoTracking()` doesn't affect the performance of the query execution against the underlying datastore, it will reduce the time that it takes the query to return, but only by skipping the process that would normally track a reference of the returned objects in the ChangeTracker.

If after clearing the change tracker, and loading the query using `.AsNoTracking()` you need further optimisations, we then need to look into the related items that are returned.

Firstly, your query is loading **ALL** records from `SiteCategory` and **ALL** of the related `Sites` and `TAudits`.  To load **ALL** of anything might be expected to take some time if there are a lot of records. The performance will be dependant on the underlying store and the complexity of the relationships that you are including.

With included navigation paths, you might benefit from using [Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#split-queries) via `.AsSlpitQuery()`. This isn't a silver bullet, but does help in many scenarios.

In scenarios where multiple navigation properties are expanded, split queries can significantly reduce the bytes transferred across the wire from the data store to your runtime. That is because without it, EF executes your expression as a single joined statement, resulting in a cartesian product of all the related tables. When you split the queries using `.AsSplitQuery()` EF will execute separate queries against each table, returning fewer rows, it then re-constructs the object graph in memory.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will look into AsSplitQuery() a little more now.

Comment: To do an actual performance deep dive would require a lot more information but if you think the query is slower than say executing in management studio or directly in the database, then `AsSplitQuery()` is a good place to start, this sounds like the type of query (no filters) that is a good candidate for that... Of course using filters would help a lot, you don't have to bring all the data into application memory,..

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to verify when looking for performance issues is where the actual time is going. So for instance:

```
Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var checklist = await _context.SiteCategory
    .Include(s => s.Sites)
    .Include(s => s.TAudits)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();

timer.Stop();  
int ms = timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
```

This will give you a figure for this specific query. If this figure does not explain the total amount of time for the action you are executing, such as rendering a page, then you may be falling foul of lazy loading. So for example you have a page which is supposed to render a list of these Site Categories, it's taking a long time to load, so you put a breakpoint on this query which is pretty much the only query in the Action figuring it's the suspect, but the query comes back in a second or so, but the page takes a minute+ to load. Chances are that as the view engine is going through each category, it is "touching" a navigation property that isn't eager loading, triggering a lazy load round trip back to the database. Multiply this times the number of rows (lazy loads will load related records for each and every row in the result set individually) and you've got a significant delay.

When looking for performance issues with EF, it is a good idea to run a profiler against the database to see exactly what queries are being run. This can highlight things like lazy loading where a page loading via a query like this you would expect to see one query, if you start seeing 10's or 100's or more queries getting kicked off for related tables, then you've tripped lay loading. The code/view engine is "touching" more navigation properties than what you have eager loaded.

If this query is notably slow, then the next thing to look at is how much data are you loading. What data do you actually need from the site category, site, and audits? Do you need ALL columns from ALL rows of these 3 tables? Eager loading an entity graph (entity and its relatives) is commonly used when loading a single top-level entity, but can be extremely expensive/wasteful when loading sets like listing all items or search results. Your statement is loading the entire table of SiteCategories, so that is potentially a lot of rows with all sites and audits. When JOINing tables, database produce a Cartesian Product across all columns, quickly resulting in a broad and deep resultset for EF to sift through to compose the entities. In situations where this data is absolutely necessary, you can mitigate this with `AsSplitQuery()` (EF Core) however, in many cases the data is not all needed, so you should consider projecting down to a ViewModel of just the data you want using `Select`. This will depend largely on how you are consuming these results. Whatever calls this query, make sure it isn't doing any further filtering like a `Where()` clause which would better be moved up into the query. If you need only a few columns from the site category and something like a Count of sites, and maybe the date of the latest Audit record, etc. these can be projected within the Linq Query. For help with that feel free to update the question with  a view or code that is consuming the results of this checklist. Projecting down results is hands-down one of the biggest bumps you can give performance after addressing issues like lazy loading.

The next consideration with this loading an entire set is if your solution is using, or should be using pagination, and server-side pagination rather than client side pagination. Many data grid controls and the like offer client-side pagination which is where they will take thousands of rows and present them in batches of 10 or 25 or so. The issue with client side pagination is that you have the expense of loading *all* data just for the client to display a few at a time. Server-side pagination has the control send the current page and page size to the server so that your query can tell the database just to return one page of results. Each time the client side control changes page or page size, it will request a new page from the server. This takes a bit more coding and coordination between client and server, but it results in much faster loading performance.

The last thing to check might be the current state of the DbContext when you kick off this operation?  For instance, is this a web application and is the _context reference lifetime-scoped to the request? Or is it using a longer-lived DbContext instance like a Singleton? If a DbContext happens to be tracking a lot of entity references that may, or may not be related to the data you are loading, then it can spend time checking all tracked references to insert into query results, whether you eager load or not. In this case a `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear();` ***prior*** to the query might speed up the query, though in reality you should look to ensure that DbContext instances are kept short-lived to avoid these types of issues as well as "poisonings" when updating data.

That should hopefully give you a few ideas on things to check once you confirm where the performance cost is actually being charged.

Answer (score -3):

The placement of `AsNoTracking()` and `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` can affect the performance of your query and how Entity Framework (EF) manages the tracked entities. However, whether using them will make your query faster depends on the specific scenario and requirements.

Here's an explanation of each and how they can impact performance:

1. `AsNoTracking()`: This method is used to indicate that the entities retrieved from the database should not be tracked by the EF context. This means that EF won't keep track of changes made to these entities and won't generate update statements for them when you save changes. It can improve query performance because EF doesn't need to maintain the state of these entities.

   - Placing `AsNoTracking()` before `Select()`, `Include()`, or `ToList()` affects all entities retrieved by the query. It's typically applied to the entire query result.
   - Use `AsNoTracking()` when you don't intend to modify the entities and want to improve query performance.
2. `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear()`: This method clears all tracked entities from the EF context's change tracker. It can be useful when you want to detach entities from the context to prevent accidental changes or to free up memory.

   - Placing `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` after you've finished working with entities (e.g., after `ToList()`) is a good practice to detach them from the context. This can help reduce memory usage and prevent tracking of changes.
   - It's not typically used for query performance improvement but rather for memory management and preventing unintentional changes to entities.

Whether using these methods will make your query faster depends on your specific use case:

- If you don't need to track changes to the entities and you're only reading data, using `AsNoTracking()` can improve query performance by avoiding the overhead of change tracking.
- `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` is more about memory management and avoiding accidental changes rather than query performance. It's a good practice to detach entities from the context when you're done with them.

In summary, you can use both `AsNoTracking()` and `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` to improve query performance and manage entities, but their placement should align with your specific requirements regarding change tracking and memory management.

Comment: Verbose answer full of ambiguity and disputable advice.